# discord.js ubuntu not connecting to gateway

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, discord, discord.js

so I used to run my discord bot strictly on my own computer, but I decided to get a VPS instead. Everything went smoothly with all of my bots until one started giving me this error in PM2.

```js
8|Bot  | [WS => Shard 2] [INVALID SESSION] Resumable: false.
8|Bot  | [WS => Shard 2] Failed to connect to the gateway, requeueing...
```

this loops. I don't know what is causing this, or why it cannot connect to the gateway using Ubuntu, but can on Windows 10. The code and files are identical. Thank you.

Comment: https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/issues/4896

Comment: does not help??